# How to submit a Form using Selenium in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using `Selenium WebDriver` to automate a system. Language is `Java`. I have done most of the things but I am stuck at one point. I need to submit a Form that contains Username, Password and Re-Entering Password fields. But when I fill them(using selenium) and click the Create Account button It didn't work.

> Here is the code,

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./ChromeDriver/chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("URL Here");

    WebElement element9 = driver.findElement(By.id("accountname"));
    element9.sendKeys(username);

    WebElement element10 = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
    element10.sendKeys(password);

    WebElement element12 = driver.findElement(By.id("reenter_password"));
    element12.sendKeys(password);
```

> I used these methods to submit the form. But none of them worked.

```
    element12.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER); //method 1

    WebElement element11 = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Complete Sign-up"));
    element11.click(); //method 2

    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("javascript:CompleteCreateAccount();"); //method 3

    WebElement element13 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='createAccountButton']/span"));
    element13.click(); //method 4

    element13.submit(); //method 5

    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element13); //method 6
```

> Form HTML got from Inspect Element,

```
<div class="leftcol">
<div id="error_display" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div class="checkout_content_box" id="cart_area">
        <form id="create_account" name="create_account" action="" onsubmit="CompleteCreateAccount(); return false; " method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="lt" id="lt" value="0">
            <div id="account_form_box">
                <div class="join_form">
                    <div class="form_row">
                        <div class="form_area">
                            <label for="accountname">Create a Steam account name</label>
                            <input type="text" maxlength="64" name="accountname" id="accountname" onchange="CheckAccountNameAvailability();">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form_notes">
                            <br>
                            <span class="input_note"><a href="javascript:CheckAccountNameAvailability();">Check availability</a></span>
                            <span id="accountname_availability" style="display: none;"></span>
                        </div>
                    <div style="clear: left;"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="form_row_choose_suggested_name" class="form_row" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="form_area">
                        <label for="choose_accountname">Available account names</label><br>
                        <select id="choose_accountname" name="choose_accountname" size="3" onchange="UpdateAccountName( this.value );">
                            <option id="suggested_name_1"></option>
                            <option id="suggested_name_2"></option>
                            <option id="suggested_name_3"></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form_notes">
                        <br>
                        <span class="choose_accountname_description">Select one or try again with another name of your choice</span>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear: left;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="rule"></div>
                <div class="form_row">
                    <div class="form_area">
                        <label for="password">Choose a password</label>
                        <input type="password" maxlength="64" name="password" id="password" onkeyup="CheckPasswordStrength()" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form_notes">
                        <div id="password_tag" class="password_tag">&nbsp;</div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear: left;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form_row">
                    <div class="form_area">
                        <label class="reenter_row" for="reenter_password">Re-enter password</label>
                        <input type="password" maxlength="64" name="reenter_password" id="reenter_password" onkeyup="ReenterPasswordChange()" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form_notes">
                        <br>
                        <div id="reenter_tag" class="password_tag">&nbsp;</div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear: left;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="rule"></div>

                <div class="form_row">
                    <div id="priv_and_sub">
                        <a id="createAccountButton" class="btnv6_blue_hoverfade btn_medium" href="javascript:CompleteCreateAccount();" style="float: right;">
                            <span>Complete Sign-up</span>
                        </a>

                        <div style="clear: right;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="ssa_submit">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

> And also I need to say when I click `Create Account button` manually it is working. But using selenium It is not working and pass this message
>
> The account name you have chosen is not available. Please choose
>   another name. The password you entered is not allowed. Please select a
>   different password, with at least 8 characters.
>
> **But username and passwords are okay. Nothing wrong. Because when I
>   click it manually It is working with that username and password.**

Comment: @MosheSlavin I don't know there are lots of elements I just added only these fields. Do I need to add whole HTML form elements?

Comment: @MosheSlavin I added whole HTML elements. Can you check?

Comment: [I think that's where you'll find the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31959659/selenium-send-keys-not-working-with-java-while-submitting-a-form)

Comment: @BaruchG. But I can see username and passwords are typing in that fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had similar issue's in the past sometimes it helps to focus on a different element then click...

I'd start with trying to *focus* on `<div id="ssa_submit"></div>`.

**EDIT:**

You say that manually it works so what I'll advise you to use `Action` like so:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement btnElement=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='createAccountButton']"));
action.doubleClick(btnElement).build().perform();
```

But it could be you really have a bug in the system...

**EDIT 2:**

A best practice in Selenium is to use `WebDriverWait` with `ExpectedConditions`:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("createAccountButton")));
```

See [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) and [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html).

I think this should do the job!

Hope this helps you.

Comment: It throws an error `Element <div id="ssa_submit">...</div> is not clickable at point`

Comment: No sir This is also not working. But thank you for helping me.

Comment: Did you see the mouse moving to the button and clicking? and it still didn't help? that is odd

Comment: @HansanaAthukorala you have +1 from me! that is a puzzle! ;)

Comment: I have updated last part of the question. Can you check that?

Comment: Yes I also can't understand what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of clicking `By.xpath("//a[@id='createAccountButton']/span")` and submitting the form, click user name, password or confirm password field and hit enter.

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./ChromeDriver/chromedriver.exe");

 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
 driver.get("URL Here");

 WebElement element9 = driver.findElement(By.id("accountname"));
 element9.sendKeys(username);

 WebElement element10 = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
 element10.sendKeys(password);

 WebElement element12 = driver.findElement(By.id("reenter_password"));
 element12.sendKeys(password);

 element12.click();
 element12.submit();
```

Comment: I have already fixed the problem. But Thank you for your answer.